# "conda update conda" only affects the environment in which it is issued?

Tags: conda, anaconda3

I launched spyder as was told to update to version 5.5.1 from 5.4.3 using:

```
conda update anaconda
conda install spyder=5.5.1
```

The 1st command above generated a flurry of output at the conda terminal prompt.  This was in the base environment.

For the 2nd command, I used judgement to issue an update instead of an install because I didn't want confusion from the possibility of two versions installed: `conda update conda`.  Furthermore, I did the update from the base environment as a test to see whether it propagates to my main working environment *py39* (for Python 3.9).  The 2nd command generated significantly less output at the conda terminal prompt, but I confirmed that Spyder got updated to 5.5.1 as expected.

When I activated *py39*, however, Spyder was still at 5.4.3.  No problem, I thought, I'll just update Spyder in the *py39* environment.  After issuing `conda update spyder`, I was surprised to see much more output at the conda prompt.  The only difference in what I did was that I did not issue `conda update conda` beforehand in the *py39* environment.

*Does this mean that issuing "conda update conda" in the base enviroinment only updates the base environment?* If so, it changes my understanding of the command prefix `conda`, which I saw as a flag to identify commands to be interpreted by a layer that transcends all environments (even though the interpreter may choose to apply the command in the context of the prevailing environment).  If the `conda` package can differ depending on the environment, then the designed-for behaviour of commands prefixed with `conda` can also differ.

Comment: Sounds like unfamiliarity with Spyder kernels. You should have only one copy of Spyder and environments should only have `spyder-kernels` installed - not their own copy of Spyder.